# How can I force setuptools detect that my package is platform specific?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-wheel, python-extensions

I'm working on improving the `setup.py` script for an open source package that supports various platforms.

On Linux, the package defines a `setuptools.Extension` for some C code that needs to be built alongside the Python code. This produces a wheel whose name indicates that it is only compatible with a particular version of CPython and a particular OS and hardware architecture.

On macOS, however, it invokes `xcodebuild` manually, and then includes that framework in `eager_resources`. Setuptools cannot detect that the resulting wheel is platform-specific, so it gives it a generic filename.

If it's possible to, I'd prefer to have `setuptools` build the Xcode project for me, but if not, can I somehow tell it that this is platform-specific? I was thinking I could include an empty extension, but that seems hacky.

Comment: are you familiar with over riding `setuptools.command.install` ?

Comment: I'm not, no. I haven't done much with setuptools before, just hacked this script to work slightly better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-wheel%5D+force+platform-specific

Answer (score 0):

This is the hacky way:

```py
# Add a dummy extension so setuptools knows this is platform-specific
try:
    os.mkdir('build')
except:
    pass
open('build/dummy.c', 'w').close()
mod1 = Extension('package._dummy', sources=['build/dummy.c'])
ext_modules.append(mod1)
```